# Is "Möchte Sie" acceptable?

Tags: verb

I've found these sentences in a book:

"Möchte Sie Banknoten mit Bildern von Kaninchen?"

and a couple of lines later:

"Welche möchte Sie lieber - mit Bildern von Kaninchen oder von Hunden?"

Is this correct? I would have expected "Möchten Sie".

The sentences are part of a conversation, so it's definitely meant to be 'Sie' rather than 'sie'. Also, the book is "A Second German Reader" by Elisabeth May (Kindle edition, 2012), so it's supposed to be teaching me modern German.

Comment: so person A is asking person B what kind B would prefer, right? Then it should be "möchten".

Comment: How old is this book? Once upon a time third person singular was used for politely addressing someone.

Comment: @CharlesAnderson: I wouldn't necessarily agree with that conclusion. Though that may be regional, I have met some Germans who adressed others in the third person (in which case "Welche möchte sie lieber?" would be the correct way to write this), especially in situations when they were unsure whether to use "du" or "Sie".

Comment: @CharlesAnderson: Bitte keine versprenkelten Korrekturen in Kommentaren ansammeln, die jeder lesen muss, sondern die Frage verbessern (Editfunktion). Die Frage muss ohne das Lesen der Kommentare verständlich sein.

Comment: Die Frage bitte in ihrem desaströsen Zustand den sie jetzt hat abwerten und schließen, bis die Fehler behoben sind. Ich fass es nicht, 7 Upvotes für diesen Schrott!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strictly speaking,

> welche möchte Sie lieber?

would mean something like

> which one likes you better?

Meaning *Sie* would be the object of *mögen*, and *welche* the subject.

Without any more context I would say that it was indeed a typo, the construction would only work in certain situations (in this case *welche* would have to refer to a previously mentioned feminine noun).

Another possibility would be that the sentence actually goes

> welche möchte **sie** lieber?

*sie* being the third person singular.

**Edit**: Judging by your comment on the question, I would say it's definitely a typo and should indeed be *möchten*.

Comment: Damn straight. +1 for being the only one to actually mention the (admittedly theoretical) context in which this would be correct as is.

Comment: Could you elaborate on an example for this context? I fail at imagining one.

Comment: A sitzt neben ihrem Freund B und telefoniert mit ihrer Schwester C. A: "Meine Schwester C fragt, ob du ihr eine Schwimmbrille leihen kannst." B: "Ja, klar. Ich habe eine mit hellen und eine mit dunklen Gläsern. Welche möchte sie lieber?"

Comment: Clinch said: welche möchte Sie lieber?

would mean something like


which one likes you better? I reply: No, that would be  möchtet

Comment: @Ornello no, _möchtet_ is the conjugation for the person _ihr_. See also: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%B6gen_%28Konjugation%29 The downvote was not appreciated ;D

Comment: @Ornello I would be careful about the sites you use. That site seems to assume that every verb that's not in its database is a regular verb or something like that. _möchten_ is **not** a full verb, it's the Konjunktiv II of the verb **mögen**, it's not a verb of its own.

Comment: @Ornello I only brought up _ihr_ because you mentioned _möchtet_, which is the conjugation for that pronoun. In this case _möchte_ is right, since, like you mentioned, _sie_ would be the right pronoun in the hypothetical context. We should continue this discussion in the chat, so we don't flood with comments.

Comment: You don't understand at all. See: http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-m%C3%B6chten.html The sentence quoted at the beginning seems to me to be incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19925/discussion-between-clinch-and-ornello).

Comment: But sie is the pronoun, not ihr, so your point is irrelevant. Do you understand what I am talking about?Apparently not. There is no combination of sie with möchte except Konjunktive I, which would require wenn or Falls or the like! It must be sie möchtet (fem third pers singular) or Sie möchten (formal) or sie möchten (third pers plural).

Comment: "möchte" *is* Konjunktiv; it's the Konjunktiv of "mögen" (and it's the Konjunktive II, not I). You (and your conjugator) seem to think that there is a verb whose infinitive is "möchten", but that is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, in both cases you need an "n"

- "Möchte**n** Sie Banknoten mit Bildern von Kaninchen?"
- "Welche möchte**n** Sie lieber - mit Bildern von Kaninchen oder von Hunden?"

It also doesn't matter if you are talking about "eine Banknote" or "zehn Banknoten". Asking a good friend, I would say "Möchte**st** Du Banknoten mit Bildern von Kaninchen?" The ending of the word relates to the person - not the "Banknoten".

In all these cases you are directly talking **to** this person, hence the polite "Sie/Du".
As a sidemark when I write a German letter I should use "ich" in lowercase and "Du/Sie" in uppercase. In English it's the other way round - for me often a problem.

In the proposed alternative "Welche möchte sie lieber?", two persons are talking about a third, no need to be polite ;-)

Comment: No, if two persons are talking about a third (female), it would be: "Welche möchtet sie lieber?" See: http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-m%C3%B6chten.html

Comment: @Ornello - Sorry but your example is wrong and doesn't exist. It's either "Welche möchte sie lieber?" (female third person), "Welche möchte er lieber?" (male third person), "Welche möchten sie lieber?" (multiple third persons) or "Welche möchtet Ihr lieber?" (direct talk to multiple persons), "Welche möchtest Du lieber?" (direct talk to one person, good known), "Welche möchten Sie lieber?" (direct talk to one person, polite). New year greetings from Switzerland.

Comment: @Ornello - Please keep your tone a bit more kindly. I must admit that I didn't had a look at reverso. However I have to remark that the use of möchten as an independent verb is disputed. See [link](http://www2.rz.hu-berlin.de/linguistik/institut/syntax/krakau2006/beitraege/reviczky_balogh.pdf) (german). Usually möchten is a flectional form of mögen. See [link](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-m%C3%B6gen.html). Now we have another special case, the so called präteritopräsens. Even if disputable, "Welche möchte sie lieber?" is the normally used form.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities what this sentence could mean, but both would contain misspells:

> 1. The sentence is a direct question to the reader and uses the polite *Sie*-form. This is implied by the capitalized *Sie*. In this case, the verb needs an *n*, just as you suspected.
> 2. The reader is being asked about the preferences of a female third person. In that case, the capital *Sie* is wrong.

To decide which meaning was intended, we'll need more context.

Comment: there are 3 possibilities. See clinch's answer.

Comment: Option 2 doesn't have to refer to a third person. In some regions, it is not completely unusual that others are adressed in the 3rd person form as "er" and "sie", respectively, when the one talking is unsure whether to use "du" or "Sie". cf., for example, [this article](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umgangsformen:_Anrede): "Eine andere Zwischenform ist (...) die dritte Person Singular (Ansprache mit „Er“)"

Comment: But it would be "Sie" (capital letter) if adressing s.o. in the third person /honorific use.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: addressing somebody using 3rd person is entirely unusual today; that’s reserved for addressing the king but Germany doesn’t have a king…

Comment: @Holger: It may not be widespread or just a regional use, but it is still somewhat common today, also among "younger" people (of, say, less than 30 years of age). As I explained, it can serve as a way to avoid the decision whether to use "du" or "Sie" when adressing someone.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: as said, most Germans would classify 3rd person addressing as even more formal than using „Sie“ (think royal) so it doesn’t make the slightest sense to use it as a compromise between „Sie“ and „Du“. If you address an average German using 3rd person (s)he would call you eccentric, at best (believe me, *I am* an average German). And everyone claiming that a particular phrase has a regional use should provide at least one provable example, otherwise its just an empty statement. I don’t know of any region for which it would be even thinkable.

Comment: @Holger: [This article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Dialekt#Das_Berliner_Er.2FWir) identifies the form as typical for Berlin, though I personally have rather encountered it outside of larger cities in Southern Germany. I will not become any more specific so as to not give away any further personal details on myself, but be assured that that form exists, is in occasional use nowadays and that it is not at all perceived as "more formal than using 'Sie'", rather - as I said - as a form of addressing e.g. young (almost-)adults where you're not sure whether to use "du" or "Sie".

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Lol, just before I started questioning my own experience as native-born Berliner I saw that the only reference is Schinkel’s Reisetagebuch from **1824**. Well I know enough about today’s German language as practiced in Berlin. But if you know that there might be some Bavarian villages where that form is used, I will not question it, however, we were talking about the *German* language, weren’t we?

Answer (score 3):

1. It is an old way of being polite: addressing your dialog partner in 3rd person.

   > [Directly talking to a female person]
   >   DE "Welche möchte Sie lieber?"
   >   EN "Which one would she like to have?"
2. The text is written in dialect spoken in Hessen, Germany (hessischer Dialekt).

   > "Welche Farbe möchte sie habe, mei Meister?"

   In this example, someone is talking to another person in plural (polite form).

Comment: Wie wird "sie" im Hessischen ausgesprochen?

Comment: You 1. may be it - at least [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=m%C3%B6chte+Er&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cm%C3%B6chte%20Er%3B%2Cc0) indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

We need more of the context to give a useful answer.

The sentence could be correct, and if it is correct its translation is:

> Which one does she prefer?

Comment: This would be right if it weren't for the capital S in _Sie_.

Comment: No, that would require the small s in sie. Capital S Sie requires möchten.

Answer (score -1):

Judging from your comment on your initial question

> Okay, the full sentences are: "Möchte Sie Banknoten mit Bildern von
>   Kaninchen?", and "Welche möchte Sie lieber - mit Bildern von Kaninchen
>   oder von Hunden?" They are part of a conversation, so it's definitely
>   meant to be 'Sie' rather than 'sie'.

"möchte" is valid, if "Sie" refers to a woman that isn't present in the scene.
Basicly the person is asking what the woman would like, bunnies or dogs.

You can read about it [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/moegen). At 2.d you (last paragraph) you can find an example similar to the one you provided.

> sie möchte (hätte gern) ein Fahrrad zu Weihnachten

Comment: I forgot to mention that "Sie" (capital letter) is perfectly fine in this case, but unusual. I don't know why the people here keep insisting otherwise.

Comment: Well, the capital letter is the indication that it is *not*  a "woman that isn't present in the scene" but a honorific second-person pronoun, and thus singular.

Comment: I think "Sie" is "Femininum Singular" and thus correct in this case

Answer (score -3):

So far as I know:

If *Sie* is capitalized, it means 'you' and takes the verb *möchten*.

If *sie* is *not* capitalized, it means 'they' if the verb is *möchten*.

If *sie* is *not* capitalized, it means 'she' if the verb is *möchtet*.

See:
[conjugation tables for möchten](http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-m%C3%B6chten.html)

If it is Konjunktive I, it would require a *wenn*, or *Falls*, I think, or it would have to be placed at the beginning of a question.

Why are people voting this down? It's the correct answer!